# Monochrome scanning software

Tags: scanner

I am new to Ubuntu and am seeing if I can move from Windows. My one problem is getting the right scanning software. In particular, I want to scan documents in 1-bit monochrome(i.e. black and white) to minimise storage but can't seem to find anything that lets me do that. All the apps I have looked at seem to only allow colour or 8-bit grayscale. Does anyone have a solution?

Thank-you.

JW

Comment: I believe gscan2pdf from ubuntu software allows you to save scanned images in grey scale as an option.

Comment: On gscan2pdf, I can set the Scan Mode to Grey or Colour and the Bit Depth to 8 or 16 but I cannot see how to get black and white or a 1 bit colour depth. It is the same with all the other software I tried.

Comment: I am just wondering might this be a driver issue? I am using a Canon Lide 200. The scanner generally works, even if it is a bit slower than under Windows. The only issue is I can't get a black and white scan.

Comment: `xsane` has this option.